# MVC 4 is overwriting specific Action-Parameters

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

MVC 4 does present me some strange behaviour at the moment.

Imagine the following Code:

**TestController.cs**

```
public class TestController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index(Function function, string action)
    {
        return View();
    }

    public class Function
    {
        public string Action { get; set; }
    }
}
```

It seems, that when I call the URL directly through the browser (localhost:PORT/Test), the Action-Property gets automatically filled with "Index".
If the Action would be named "MySuperDuperActionWhichGetsInvokedQuiteOften", exactly this Methodname would be in the property.

Can somebody explain what MVC is doing here?
The Problem is, that I of course want to fill that stuff myself, for example through an AJAX-Query. But if MVC is filling in this property all by itself, this breaks some behaviour.

I could, of course, just rename my property and it would be working, but it would still be quite interesting what's going on.

**EDIT**

I would understand it that my second parameter, string action, get's filled with the method-name. But why on earth would MVC bind **any** property/parameter that is named the same to the request-value of it?

Comment: Are you saying that when you navigate to `localhost/test` the value of `function.Action` is "Index"?

Comment: That is exactly what I tried to say.

Answer (score 0):

It is problem with default model binder. It "maps" request fields to properties in your class. There is an article of [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/hh781022.aspx) describing how does it works but to simply this situation the code will be like this:

```
Action = Request["action"] //where of course Request["action"] equals to name of your action
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. See my edited question to see what I actually want to know.